# Use "use" in ext_localconf.php in TYPO3? (Fatal error: Cannot use ... as ... because the name is already in use in)

Tags: typo3

I just had an error because of this:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility
as GeneralUtility because the name is already in use
in /var/www/mysite/public/typo3temp/var/cache/code/cache_core/ext_localconf_feb178af00fe22e00dc62d7dcd6d4d16f5d4fc3a.php
on line 4508
```

Reason was the following line in a file `ext_localconf.php` of an extension:

```
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
```

Apparently, some extensions use "use" in `ext_localconf.php` on my system. As this is all concatenated into one file in the cache, this can lead to multiple use statements.

Is there still some way to use "use" without causing these errors? What is the recommended way?

---

**Update**: As stated [in the answer by Rudy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60300753/2444812), since TYPO3 v11, it is possible to use "use" also in ext_localconf.php, ext_tables.php etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Updated for TYPO3 11**: With 11.4 the files ext_localconf.php and ext_tables.php are scoped into the global namespace on being warmed up from the cache. Therefore **use statements can now be used inside these files**.

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/ConfigurationFiles/Index.html

---

For older versions < v11:

`use` used for importing/aliasing namespaces in PHP can only be used in global scope, not in block scope. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php#language.namespaces.importing.scope. So you shouldn't use `use` at all in `ext_localconf.php` and just use full namespaces instead.

If there are extensions that do use `use` in `ext_localconf.php` you should let the maintainers of that extension know this is wrong and can (and will) cause fatal errors.

Comment: Conigurations in ext_localconf.php and ext_tables.php are merged into Cache file. And this merge can not respect any importing/aliasing namespaces.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will let the maintainers know next time I see this. One pull request has already been submitted ...

Comment: Please also see Best practices for ext_localconf.php and ext_tables.php in the documentation, where this is also mentioned: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/ConfigurationFiles/Index.html

Comment: Was changed in TYPO3 v11: You can now use use in ext_localconf.php and ext_tables.php, see https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/ConfigurationFiles/Index.html (I updated the answer)